# Speed of directory look-up vs. formatted filename look-up

Tags: windows, filesystems

I've had this discussion with my co-worker multiple times now, and I'm 99.9% sure that I'm correct, but they have been insisting that they are correct and I'm starting to wonder if I'm the crazy one.

We are uploading images taken from users from their mobile devices, cumulatively they could upload thousands given enough time. Each of these photos belong to a "work orders", which are given a sequential integer. We want to optimize for *retrieval* (based on the work order) rather than writing. We are also on a Windows machine.

My proposed storage method looks like this:

```
Images
|-- 23875
|    |-- f0347b8.png
|    |-- b04675b.png
|-- 28765
     |-- aab658c.png
```

Their proposed storage method looks like this:

```
Images
|-- 23875_f0347b8.png
|-- 23875_b04675b.png
|-- 28765_aab658c.png
```

For me, in order to gather the 2 images for work order `23875`, I would look in the directory, `Images/23875` and grab all the `.png` files.

For them to do the same thing, they would iterate through all the files and run a wildcard filter on all the filenames, something to effect of `23875_*.png`.

I believe my method to be superior because, in the case where there are, say, thousands of images, it doesn't need to run a wildcard filter on potentially thousands of irrelevant files. I've asked why they believe their method to be superior, but I haven't gotten a compelling answer.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method

```
Images
|-- 23875_f0347b8.png
|-- 23875_b04675b.png
|-- 28765_aab658c.png
```

requires iterating through ***every single file*** in `Images` to find all files that match `23875_*`.  Every single time you want to find them.  Over and over. Until the world ends and the stars go dark.

Putting all the files in one directory discards information you have when you create the file, thus making the file harder to locate in the future.  Trying to encode that information in the file name means the data is mixed in with all other similar data and therefore needs to be filtered out in the future.

Why?  You're right - it makes no sense.  It's tossing information in the garbage for no good reason.

Your method

```
Images
|-- 23875
|    |-- f0347b8.png
|    |-- b04675b.png
|-- 28765
     |-- aab658c.png
```

has already partitioned the files into the required associations.  No filtering or searching is needed to find the files.

> they have been insisting that they are correct

Oooh-kay.  Maybe they like this sort of wrestling...